# Python 2: Handling unicode in a string when you dont have control of the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

So I'm using TwitterSearch Library. The function is simple, to print Twitter search result.

So here's a trouble. Your tweet is passed by The TwitterSearch from this dict (or list. Whatever is the actual one is)

```
tweet['text']
```

And if your python 2.7 have an unicode that this python can't solve, BOOM. Program Err

So I tried to make it like thise

```
a=unicode(tweet['text'], errors='ignore')
print a
```

The purpose is that I want the unicode converted to string, while ignoring unresolved unicode in the process (This is what I understand from the documentation. I may fail to understand the documentation so come up with this code)

I got this cute Error message.

```
typeError: decoding Unicode is not suported
```

My question

1: Why? Doesn't this Unicode stuff is part of default python Library

2: What should I do so I can I have unicode converted to string, while ignoring unresolved unicode in the process

PS: This is my first unicode issue and this is the best I can do at this point. Don't kill me.

Comment: `tweet['text']` is **already** a unicode string. What unicode error did you see? Are you perhaps trying to *print* on a console that doesn't support the specific characters, or are you trying to write to a file without explicit encoding, or concatenating to other non-unicode strings?

Comment: So. What should I do so I can convert it to string and strip any other unresolved unicode

Comment: That depends on the context, you didn't give us anything to go on here.

Comment: You want to read [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) and the [Python Unicode Howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), with a sprinkling of the [Joel on Software on Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) before you continue.

Comment: I read the Unicode Howto. In fact, the reason I got that unicode stuff is from that documentation. I maybe read a stuff and get the whole thing wrong perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the distinction between Unicode objects and byte strings. In Python 2.7 `unicode` class is a Unicode object. These already consist of characters defined in the Unicode standard. From my understanding of the evidence you've provided, your `tweet['text']` is already a `unicode` instance.

You can verify this by printing `type(tweet['text'])`:

```
>>> print type(tweet['text'])
<type 'unicode'>
```

Now `unicode` objects are a high-level representation of a concept that does not have a single defined representation in computer memory. They are very useful as they allow you to use characters outside of the ASCII standard range that is limited to basic latin letters and numbers. But a character in Unicode is not remembered by the computer as its shape, instead we use their numbers provided by the standard and referred to as *code points*.

On the other hand pretty much every part of your computer operates using bytes. Network protocols transfer bytes, input and output streams transfer bytes. To be able to send a Unicode string across the network or even print it on a device such as your terminal you need to use a protocol that both communicating parties (e.g. your program and the terminal) understand. We call these encodings.

```
>>> u'żółw'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc5\xbc\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82w'
>>> print type(u'żółw'.encode('utf-8'))
<type 'str'>
```

There are many encoding and a single `unicode` object can often be encoded into many different byte strings depending on the encoding you choose. To pick one that is correct requires the knowledge of the context you want to use the resulting string in. If your terminal understands UTF-8 then all `unicode` objects will require encoding to UTF-8 before being sent to the output stream. If it only understands ASCII then you might need to drop some of the characters.

```
>>> print u'żółw'.encode('utf-8')
żółw
```

So if Python's default output encoding is either incorrect or cannot handle all the characters you're trying to print, you can always encode the object manually and output the resulting `str` instead. But before you do, please read all of the documents linked to in comments directly under your question.

Comment: It seems that right syntax is encode not unicode. Must be misunderstanding of the documentation. Thank you for telling the way to enlighten. :)